# Appium error occurs after opening app in emulator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am not able to perform click operation  when the application is opened. 
I got the below error in command prompt.
`[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 32617 ms - 741`

Comment: a 200 (sucess) POST request is not an error message..?

Comment: 741 is an error.i am using Cucumber framework with appium, in emulator app was opened after that clicking was not possible in that time above mention error occurs.@chevybow